# mongodb element match and update query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection named `users` details below

```
[{
"userId": "00UPQAARGT7",
"userPreferences": [{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D48CB",
    "pData": [{
            "name": "FORMAT",
            "value": "CSV"
        },
        {
            "name": "LAN",
            "value": "E"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D59DB",
    "pData": [{
            "name": "FORMAT",
            "value": "DOC"
        },
        {
            "name": "LAN",
            "value": "N"
        }
    ]
}
]},
{
"userId": "02UPQAARST7",
"userPreferences": [
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D48DB",
    "pData": [{
            "name": "FORMAT",
            "value": "CSV"
        },
        {
            "name": "LAN",
            "value": "N"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D59DB",
    "pData": [{
            "name": "FORMAT",
            "value": "PPT"
        },
        {
            "name": "LAN",
            "value": "N"
        }
    ]
}
]}  
]
```

I want to set `userPreferences.pData.value` to `"TAB"` where `userPreferences.pData.name` is `"FORMAT"` and `userPreferences.pData.value` to `"FRN"` where `userPreferences.pData.name` is `"LAN"` but want to apply condition 
where `userId` in `["00UPQAARGT7", "02UPQAARST7"]` and `userPreferences.pId` in `["59SDS64675A00096D48CB","59SDS64675A00096D59DB"]`

any help how to do in mongodb with single query

I'm using mongodb 3.4.1 version

Comment: I'd suggest you try re-frame your question first. I have a headache after reading it and I didn't even make it to the end.

Comment: have you tried https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/ at all?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this the way you want to for two reasons:

1. In MongoDB 3.4 the [positional operator '$'](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/update/positional/) only matches the first found subdocument. This has been changed in v3.6 where you can now use the [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) syntax to target all matching subdocuments.
2. You cannot specify a conditional update in any version of MongoDB as of today. There is an open feature request for this, though: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6566

So you are basically left with the good old (unfortunately slower) alternative of doing the changes on the client side which you can find loads of examples for, e.g. here:

[MongoDB update multiple subdocuments with or query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904007/mongodb-update-multiple-subdocuments-with-or-query)

[Update all sub-documents inside document mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400845/update-all-sub-documents-inside-document-mongodb)